# word for a person who gives the gift

Tags: single-word-requests

In another question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207755/what-do-you-call-someone-whom-a-gift-is-intended-for?rq=1) I got the word for a person to whom the gift is intended for.

Is there any word for a person who gives the gift?

As per [this](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/giver) link giver means benefactor, donor, contributor etc. but there is no specific word which can be used in gift context.

[This](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gifter) link shows gifter as a word (noun).

Comment: See http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/giver?s=t

Comment: It gives synonyms for giver. I have asked the question for gift giver.

Comment: _Santa Claus_  or _Gifter_  may be?!

Comment: I think gifter is the right word.

Comment: Using *gift* as a verb doesn't sit that right.

Comment: From the list of synonyms _benefactor, bestower and presenter_ would all be relevant but each would only apply to a specific sort of gift under specific circumstances. I can't imagine anyone saying "I got these socks for my birthday, the bestower was my Aunt Jane" unless they were being very ironic. The most general term is actually _giver_ but even that isn't used much, people tend to say "Who gave you that?" or "My aunt Jane gave me that." rather than "Who was the giver of that?" or "My Aunt Jane was the giver of that". However for formal charitable gifts the most usual term is _donor_.

Comment: Say we're taking notes about who gave what gift for a special occasion.  I'll jot down two simple column headings: "giver," or "who," and "gift," "present," or "what."  So, with the right context, "giver" does the trick. // "To gift" as a verb is something I've heard in the U.S. in the last few years, but I can't say I like it.

Answer (score 4):

The word you want, I suspect, is ***donor***, but that would apply mostly to charitable giving. Another possibility is ***benefactor***, though it is more frequently used nowadays to refer to those who leave money in wills. If it is simply for use as part of a commercial software system involving the ordering and sending of things to another party, I think *giver* might be the simplest and best term to use.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your answer? It's been flagged as low-quality.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit your answer to add *probably* after "you" and then announce that I'd fixed the low-quality flag issue.

Comment: @deadrat Well who's flagged it as "low quality", and what exactly do they mean by that?  The *I suspect* does essentially the same thing as *probably* would, by simply accepting that what I am stating carries uncertainty.

Comment: I don't know who flagged it. If it was a member of the CPVPV, I suspect (see what I did there?) they mean you've let down the side. Do I have to start marking such of my comments as facetious?

Comment: @deadrat I'm not sure how one flags for "low quality". When I click on *flag* I'm given various options - *spam*, *rude and abusive* etc, but "low quality" is not one of them. I presume that it was the box which calls for *moderator intervention*. So what is *low quality*? Sounds like a euphemism to me. It will be interesting to find out what a moderator thinks. If I flagged all the answers I thought were "low quality" I'd be doing nothing else.

Comment: I'd guess that "in need of moderator intervention" let's you specify. I'm not sure either. All I've ever flagged was obvious spam.

Comment: @deadrat I have been through my own list of flag actions, over three years - the vast majority of which have been adjudged "helpful" and I note that some of them have been categorised *low quality*, or *very low quality*. I don't think this is an expression I would use, so I assume it is a form of shorthand used by moderators.

Comment: Probably the same form I use *for* moderators.

Comment: The low-quality flag was probably automatic. The metric the system uses are not publicised, but do include length. This answer **is** low quality and the flag should have been upheld. **Why** is *donor* suspected to be right? Please provide corroboration.

Comment: @Rathony I read it. Thanks, I think. Are you sure you're a normal user?

Comment: @Rathony They alway are, I guess.

Comment: @Rathony *They* is the third person indeterminate. In my last answer, *they* refers to people who are sure they're normal. Just my little joke. You may ignore it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Why is *donor* suspected to be right? Because that's the definition of *donor*, and corroboration would be a reference to a source that says that's what the definition of *donor* is. At some point, the demand for references becomes a fetish and not an actual aid to understanding.